# Função executando direto

Tags: javascript

Quando eu clico no botão 'novo' chamando a função para verificar os dados, dentro dela eu chamo outra função para verificar a data que foi informada!

```
function f_veri_dados()
{
    // existem outros dados
    // Data da Garantia
    f_veri_data(tx_dt_gtia);
    parent.location.replace("#"); --> chama outra aba se a verificação estiver certa
}
```

Verificação de data:

```
function f_veri_data(w_data)
    { 
    w_form_dt="#";          
    w_tx_data = w_data.value;

    if (w_tx_data == "")
    {
    alert("Informe a data!!!");
    document.forms[w_form_dt].tx_dt_gtia.focus();   
    return false;
    }
  var w_datavalor = "";
  var w_dia, w_mes, w_ano = "";

  //Retira caracteres que não sejam números.
  var digitos="0123456789";
  for (w_i = 0; w_i < w_tx_data.length; w_i++)
      if (digitos.indexOf(w_tx_data.substr(w_i,1)) != -1)
         w_datavalor = w_datavalor+w_tx_data.substr(w_i,1);
  //Verifica a validade da data propriamente dita.


  if (w_datavalor.length > 5)
     {
     if (w_datavalor.length == 6){
         w_datavalor =w_datavalor.substr(0,4) + '20' +w_datavalor.substr(4,2);
    }
     w_dia = w_datavalor.substr(0,2);
     w_mes = w_datavalor.substr(2,2);
     w_ano = w_datavalor.substr(4,4);
     //Se o dia ou o mês forem maiores ele invalida a data.
     w_data_valida = new Date(w_ano,w_mes-1,w_dia);
     w_dia_val = w_data_valida.getDate();
     w_mes_val = w_data_valida.getMonth();

     if ((w_dia_val == w_dia) && (w_mes_val+1 == w_mes))
        {
        w_data.value = w_dia + "/" + w_mes + "/" + w_ano;
        return true;
        }
     }   
  w_tx_data.value = "";   
  alert(" Data inválida.");
  document.forms[w_form_dt].qtde_nf.focus();
  return false;
  }
```

O problema é: "Ele confirma que a data está invalida, mas ainda assim continua executando o programa chamando a outra aba!". Deve ser algum erro que eu não consiga ver, se alguém conseguir ver esse erro .. Agradeço se me informar!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está a esquecer uma cláusa para verificar o resultado de `f_veri_data(tx_dt_gtia);`, ou seja o retorno da `f_veri_data()` não está a ser usado.

Faça assim:

```
function f_veri_dados()
{
    // existem outros dados
    // Data da Garantia
    if (!f_veri_data(tx_dt_gtia)) return false; // aqui para o código se o retorno da outra função fôr false
    parent.location.replace("#"); --> chama outra aba se a verificação estiver certa
}
```